# Bones for my mesh will not move with the mesh even though the mesh itself moves just fine

Tags: animation

[image: bones not moving with rigged mesh even though the mesh itself moves fine]

Bones not moving with rigged mesh even though the mesh itself moves fine

Comment: hello, probably a bad weight and you need to correct a bit, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Probably thoose bones are part of the Metarig, which is unuseful after the rig has been generated. Simply turn it off (but don't delete it, because it can be useful later for tweaks or modifications of the actual rig).

If you're looking for the deforming bones, search and activate the "DEF" bone layer (4.0 and above) or the 29th bone layer (3.6 and below, counting from 0 to 31).